# Is there a receiving API for FedEx and other common US small package carriers

Tags: web-apps, api, web-services

We receive a lot of Packages from FedEX and UPS, etc. I'm looking to find some kind of service where I can input the package tracking number into my internal company website and then call "some api" to give me the information about the package. I'm looking for the origin, destination, dimensions, weight, and piece count. This is to save manually entering the data. I found easypost.com which seems to be a third party for dealing with multiple carriers but they're focused on shipping only. Not receiving.

Is there a third party service that might do this for me? Or do I need to try and work with each carrier individually and assuming so do they have api's for that information? I know there's some commercial software that does things like this but I would like to integrate with our current systems which is java and XPages based.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Does it need to be gratis?

Comment: No not at all.  I'm happy paying a fair price for that data.  That's why I'd love to find a 3rd party that talked to the different carriers rather then my having to do it all individually myself.